# What is the easiest way to change the inner value type in a nested map in java?

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-map

I have a nested map `Map<String, Map<String, List<ObjectA>>>` passed to me, and I want to change it to type `Map<String, Map<String, Set<ObjectA>>>`, what is the easiest way to do so in Java using stream? I have tried to use Collectors.groupingBy but can't get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is you have to iterate through each entry in outer map and inner map, and then convert the inner map entry value `List<ObjectA>` to `Set<ObjectA>`

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<ObjectA>>> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, val -> new HashSet<>(val.getValue())))));
```

**Note :** If you are converting `List` to `HashSet` then you will not maintain same order, so you can choose `LinkedHashSet` over `HashSet` to maintain order

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<ObjectA>>> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, val -> new LinkedHashSet<>(val.getValue())))));
```